# Using JavaScript onclick() to change an image

Tags: javascript, html, image, onclick

I want to be able to click on a li element for a side menu and it should make an image appear of change the current one to another.

This is the coding I have which should work but it doesn't and I dont know if I missed something or what is wrong.

```
<aside>
    <ul>
        <li onClick="document.getElementById('plantImg').src blanket">Blanket Flower</li>
        <li onclick="document.getElementById('plantImg').src rugosa">Hedge Rose</li>
        <li onclick="document.getElementById('plantImg').src bluestem">Little Bluestem</li>
    </ul>
</aside>

  <article>
     <figure>
     <img src="#" width="640" height="400" alt="" title="" id="plantImg"/>
         <figcaption>
            <script>
            /*
                Information on available plants
                including link to USDA website
            */
            document.write("<p>Plant choices for <a href= 'http://planthardiness.ars.usda.gov'> hardiness zones</a> 5a-6b</p>");// hardiness zones for Chicago and surrounding area

                var blanket = "images/blanket.jpg";
                var bluestem = "images/bluestem.jpg";
                var rugosa = "images/rugosa.jpg";
        </script>
        </figcaption>
     </figure>
  </article>
```

Thank you.

Comment: I see 3 images, which one should it change to?

Comment: To clarify: Do you mean you want onClick() to be used to 'cycle' through these 3 images referenced in string variables?

Comment: I want to use onClick to change the image that is right under <figure> with the # to the variable/ image blanket.jpg or bluestem/jpg when I click on the <li> with the name on it sorry it looks like the <li> weren't added 
 <aside>
         <ul>
            <li onClick="document.getElementById('plantImg').src blanket">Blanket Flower</li>
            <li onclick="document.getElementById('plantImg').src rugosa">Hedge Rose</li>
            <li onclick="document.getElementById('plantImg').src bluestem">Little Bluestem</li>
         </ul>
      </aside>

Comment: @alice83—don't post code in comments, edit your question if necessary. To assign to the *src* property you must use the assignment `=` operator: `document.getElementById('plantImg').src = blanket`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do it like you wanted but no need for  document.write  .

```html
<aside>
    <ul>
        <li onClick="LoadImage(blanket)" style="cursor: pointer;" >Blanket Flower</li>
        <li onclick="LoadImage(rugosa)" style="cursor: pointer;" >Hedge Rose</li>
        <li onclick="LoadImage(bluestem)" style="cursor: pointer;">Little Bluestem</li>
    </ul>
</aside>

  <article>
     <figure>
     <img src="#" width="640" height="400" alt="" title="" id="plantImg"/>
         <figcaption>
            <script>
            
            function LoadImage ( src_ ) {
                  
              document.getElementById('plantImg').src = src_;
              
            }
            
                var blanket = "https://ckeditor.com/tmp/4.4.0/assets/js.png";
                var bluestem = "https://tag.ruuvi.com/assets/images/ruuvi-tag-javascript.png";
                var rugosa = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/ce/Unofficial_JavaScript_logo.svg/1024px-Unofficial_JavaScript_logo.svg.png";
                
                
                
        </script>
        </figcaption>
     </figure>
  </article>
```